# Why Google map does not work on the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, vue.js

Good afternoon, please tell me who knows, I am now learning to add a Google map to the site and do it with [this article](https://habr.com/ru/post/338568/). I did everything as it was indicated, but the card does not work, please tell me why? Where did I make a mistake? Api-key is correct 100%.  [And I turn on the map in Google Cloud Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zrsd.png). I use Vue cli Webpack-simple. [My project on GitHub](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/GoogleMap)

[Screenshot of a broken map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLrR6.png)

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT3M9.png)

Code of index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>google_map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Component Google.map:

```
<template>
   <div class="google-map" :id="name"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: 'google-map',
        props: ['name'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                map: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            mapMarkers: function () {
                return this.markers
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            const element = document.getElementById(this.name)
            const options = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.93, 30.32)
            }
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options)
        },
        methods: {}
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .google-map {
        width: 640px;
        height: 480px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: gray;
    }
</style>
```

Code of App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <google-map :name="name"></google-map>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import googleMap from './components/googleMap.vue'

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                name: 'map',
                  }
        },
        mounted: function () {
        },
        components: {googleMap}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: give a console  full error and checking your git repo code

Comment: Screenshot of console I add to question

Comment: yah i see your error is google not `google is not defined`

i suggest you try to vue google map package its better

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot  npm install --save google-maps and import GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps' in my google component

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot npm install --save google-maps and import GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps' in my google component  but googleMap don't work

Comment: welcome 
yah right i check your package json file its not saved

Comment: Please tell me What I must to do?

Comment: i think you have to do try another package

wait i suggest you better package for this

Comment: I changed my code a bit, look please https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/GoogleMap

Comment: wait checking .

Comment: I now have a different site, when I comment on my import, the map appears for a second and then abruptly writes that "There was a problem loading Google Maps on this page." If I reload the page, the site becomes as it was. If I uncomment the import, the map appears for a second and then abruptly writes that "There was a problem loading Google Maps on this page."

Comment: yah right i see but again see blank screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195407/discussion-between-andrey-belichenko-and-developer).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original code, before you started trying to use `GoogleMapsLoader`, your error was very simple; you were trying to use `window.google` in the compiled JS, before it was loaded through `googleapis.com`. To fix, in your index.html, simply change this:

```html
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]"></script>
```

To this:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]"></script>
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to use `GoogleMapsLoader`, please follow [the documentation they provide](https://github.com/Carrooi/Js-GoogleMapsLoader#readme); you should be wrapping any calls to the Google Maps API inside a callback function that the loader calls. There are a bunch of different approaches to how to do this, and almost definitely a better way to set up a global instance, but to at least make your code work, this is how you would need to code your mounted function:

```
mounted: function () {
    GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = '[MY_API_KEY]';
    GoogleMapsLoader.load(function(google){
        const element = document.getElementById(this.name)
        const options = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.93, 30.32)
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options)
    }.bind(this));
}
```